# Enable Back button in azure ad b2c custom policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a multi step user journey in custom policy. I need to enable a back button to move back the previous step. Is this possible in AD B2C custom policy? Please help.

Comment: All the steps are in the same page. Why do you need to move back to the previous step. Please add more details.

Comment: @AllenWu I have a sign up form. First it receives City from user then user clicks continue and in the next screen user can enter personal details like Name, email and phone etc. Now it is not possible to go back and change city entered. I need to add a button "Back" in the screen to go back and change the city.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to go back in the B2C user journey.
One method some people employed is a single SelfAsserted step, with all claims presented in the Technical Profile. But use JavaScript in your custom HTML to turn that into a multi page experience for the user, behind the scenes is a single page, and single submit.

Comment: For the workaround solution, I think it might introduce some security problems.
In the MVC concept, we shouldn't put the "controller" work into the "View" layer.
It is better to handle it from a safety area, such as the XML side, and that's why we called it the orchestration step. The reason I put this comment is just worry someone is using this workaround solution and applying it to their project. correct me if i am wrong, Thank you